The LOCATION property may not be read from target "libprotobuf"
I have some error messages while running CMake, but don't quite understand what I have to do with it:
CMake Error at cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/arm64-osx/share/protobuf/protobuf-module.cmake:98 (get_target_property):
The LOCATION property may not be read from target "libprotobuf".  Use the
target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.
Error appears here:     get_target_property(${name}_LIBRARY_RELEASE protobuf::lib${filename}
LOCATION_RELEASE)
Context: Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/arm64-osx/share/protobuf/protobuf-module.cmake:124 (_protobuf_find_libraries)
cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/arm64-osx/share/protobuf/protobuf-config.cmake:168 (include)
cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/arm64-osx/share/protobuf/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:16 (_find_package)
/Users/admin/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:813 (include)
cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/arm64-osx/share/grpc/gRPCConfig.cmake:9 (find_package)
/Users/admin/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:857 (_find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
Corresponding line in CMakeLists is find_package(gRPC REQUIRED)
